# Wordpress subscriber and contributor user roles has same permissions

Tags: wordpress

I've got a users permission problem on my wordpress website.
Subscriber role user has access to dashboard, comments, etc. like it has contributor permission.

I've tried to disable all plugins and change theme but it didn't no effect.

How can i return subscriber's permission to defaults (only user profile edit).

[[Users roles screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIvgJ.png)

[[Contributor's dashboard screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZRYK.png)

[[Subscriber's dashboard screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lg8g.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in database

options table -> wp_user_roles option

Problem was soved by removing string 's:10:"edit_posts";b:1' in subscriber capabilities.